# How to correctly append form-data files

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I am failing to run ExtractTable's API in Javascript. More exactly, the issue occurs when I try to do HTTP POST to trigger a job.

API docs: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/6396033/SVfMS9xu

I am using the code below:

```js
var FormData = require('form-data');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

var data = new FormData();
data.append("input", fileInput.files[0], "myImg.png");
data.append("dup_check", "False");

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  if(this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "https://trigger.extracttable.com");
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", "<myAPIkey>");

xhr.send(data);
```

My error message is this: "ReferenceError: fileInput is not defined".

Any ideas on what I need to do or fix in order to be able to run the above code?

Answer (score 0):

```
data.append("input", fileInput.files[0], "myImg.png");
```

You're using `fileInput.files[0]` variable but where it is define in your code ?

And you're tried to access to `fileInput.files` at index 0, maybe this index doesn't exist ?

Comment: You're right, thanks. I'm still stuck on this and am wondering if you have any idea if it is possible to append a local file to the formData. My question resembles this unanswered one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61489137/appending-file-to-formdata-from-local-disk